# Jenkinsfile: connect to a server and perform operations on the server

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkinsfile I am trying to login to a server and from there run docker-compose. However, I am getting an `AccessDeniedException` error. Root user has permissions to all folders on the server.

I assume I have a thinking error: I suspect that after ssh to the server, the `dir` command doesn't not run in the server but rather where the jenkins is run.

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        PATH = "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
    }

    stages {

        stage('Deploy to digital ocean') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['my-private-ssh-key']) {

                    sh """
                            ssh root@host
                        """
                     dir("/var/www/car_prices"){
                        sh "docker-compose down"

                     }

                 }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Error stack:

```
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/www/car_prices
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 67144 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[Pipeline] // sshagent
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/www
```

Question:
 1. Why does it throw an error?

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, the `dir` step runs on the Jenkins master.

Comment: @zett42 what would be the best way to do what I intend to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ssh` to do the job for you, which is rather straight forward:

```java
...
sshagent(['my-private-ssh-key']) {
    sh """
        ssh root@host "cd /var/www/car_prices; docker-compose down"
    """
}
...
```

This is kind of ugly, but works. If you care, you can split commands into multiple lines for better readability. This approach becomes even trickier if you want to provide some more complex functionality, like error handling.

Comment: What would be then a not ugly way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know if there's any. I'm doing this as above and it works for me. It would look better if commands were executed on slave (so if your host was a slave), but it's not always an option.